# Editing others post to maintain QA format

Tags: discussion

This is about a really worthy post but not in QA style. I asked OP to put it that way, but still he’s unaware of SO concepts as a new user.

Shall I go ahead & edit this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49565233/7920473), is it ok to split others post into Q&A? Or should we leave it as it is?

Comment: In this case, I think this user really just needed some direction. I've explained a bit better in the comments and even pointed them to the help center. We'll see what that does. In the more general case, this has been asked before.

Comment: The post should be closed, IMO. Nothing stops you from creating your own self-answered question based on this content if the OP doesn't want to do it themselves (Kendra's advice is very good, let's hope the OP takes it).

Comment: In my experience, when self-answers are edited into questions after an OP solves their own problem (cf. the duplicate suggested by @Kendra ) the OPs tend to respond well to comments in the vein of "I suggest moving your solution to an answer". I suspect convincing the OP in this case, in which the OP didn't intend to ask a question to begin with, might require some extra effort at persuasion (Kendra's comment there was a good move).

Comment: Just as a small update, it looks like the OP changed his post to a Q&A! I don't have the expertise to know if it's a good question/answer or not, but mission accomplished!

Comment: @Kendra yes, I saw that, removed my comment & flagged to remove unneeded other comments. Thanks Kendra for the leading the mission :)